# RadWindow shrink down

Tags: c#, telerik, radwindow

I am facing an issue with `Telerik RadWindow` popup. I have a page with `RadWindow` popup. There is a grid in the page and each row having a link. Whenever I click the link, it will open the RadWindow popup. It is good. But if I close and reopen the RadWindow popup multiple times, the RadWindow popup getting shrunk little bit from all the sides each time.

I need to fix this issue. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself fixed this issue. The attributes **`MinWidth`** and **`MinHeight`** added to the `<telerik:RadWindow>` and assign the same `Width` and `Height` attribute values.

**Code (before fix):**

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager" runat="server">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="radWindowPopup" Behavior="Close" VisibleTitlebar="false"
            Modal="true" runat="server" Width="725px" Height="500px" VisibleStatusbar="false"
            BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"
            CenterIfModal="true" OnClientClose="closePopup" Style="overflow: hidden;">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

**Code (Fixed):** - (*MinWidth* and *MinHeight* added with same value of *Width* and *Height* attributes)

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager" runat="server">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="radWindowPopup" Behavior="Close" VisibleTitlebar="false"
            Modal="true" runat="server" MinWidth="725px" MinHeight="500px" 
            Width="725px" Height="500px" VisibleStatusbar="false"
            BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"
            CenterIfModal="true" OnClientClose="closePopup" Style="overflow: hidden;">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

*Hope this helps*